# How to make Vector3 fields behave like the ones from Transform in a CustomEditor

Tags: unity-game-engine, custom-controls, unity3d-editor, unity-editor

In the following gif you can see the difference between how `Vector3` fields behave in the Inspector of `Transform` and of my `MonoBehaviour`s.

[image]

The `Transform` is even a `CustomEditor` I also wrote using `EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field()`.

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(Transform), true)]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class AdvancedTransformEditor : Editor
{
    //Unity's built-in editor
    private Editor _defaultEditor;
    private Transform _transform;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        //When this inspector is created, also create the built-in inspector
        _defaultEditor = CreateEditor(targets, Type.GetType("UnityEditor.TransformInspector, UnityEditor"));
        _transform = target as Transform;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        //When OnDisable is called, the default editor we created should be destroyed to avoid memory leakage.
        //Also, make sure to call any required methods like OnDisable
        var disableMethod = _defaultEditor.GetType().GetMethod("OnDisable", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
        if (disableMethod != null) disableMethod.Invoke(_defaultEditor, null);
        DestroyImmediate(_defaultEditor);
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Local Space", EditorStyles.boldLabel);
        _defaultEditor.OnInspectorGUI();

        serializedObject.Update();

        //Show World Space Transform
        EditorGUILayout.Space();
        EditorGUILayout.LabelField("World Space", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

        _transform.position = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Position", _transform.position);

        EditorGUI.BeginDisabledGroup(true);
        EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Rotation", _transform.eulerAngles);
        EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Scale", _transform.lossyScale);
        EditorGUI.EndDisabledGroup();

        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

It only works while having `_defaultEditor.OnInspectorGUI();` so something in Unity's original editor for the `Transform` component has to do something different.

When I try to do the same in any other `CustomEditor` for a `MonoBehaviour`

```c#
// without a CustomEditor
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 example;
}
```

and

```c#
// Width the custom editor
public class ExampleMinWidth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector3 example;
}

[CustomEditor(typeof(ExampleMinWidth))]
public class ExampleMinWidthEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty example;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        example = serializedObject.FindProperty("exmaple");
    }

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        serializedObject.Update();
        example.vector3Value = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Example", example.vector3Value);

        // I tried both also simply using a PropertyField
        //EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(example);
        serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
    }
}
```

or skipping the line `_defaultEditor.OnInspectorGUI();` in the `AdvancedTransformEditor` the `Vector3` field gets folded for a certain Inspector width.

**How can I get the same behaviour for my fields as for the `Transform` component - not folding but staying on the same line?**

---

**Update**

- I tried it with `GUILayout.MinWidth()` but this didn't change anything.
- As suggested I also tried

  ```c#
  example.vector3Value = EditorGUILayout.Vector3Field("Example", example.vector3Value, GUILayout.ExpandHeight(false));
  ```

  (also for the `PropertyField()`) but that didn't change anything.
- And Just for trying I also did with `ExpandWidth(false)` ... the outcome is not very pleasing :D

  [image]
- I even tried `GUILayout.MaxHeight(EditorGUIUtility.singleLineHeight)` but that makes the field still fold but "bload"/overdraw into the field below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the relevant lines in the [TransformInspector](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/95eee03f136b8bf8a9afd5d43fef5b919ba90c55/Editor/Mono/Inspector/TransformInspector.cs)

```c#
if (!EditorGUIUtility.wideMode)
{
    EditorGUIUtility.wideMode = true;
    EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - 212;
}
```

- [EditorGUIUtility.wideMode](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility-wideMode.html) does two things: **Returns** whether the editor currently **is** in widemode and **set** whether the editor for this component / the next lines shall be behaving like it was in widemode. So they simply force their fields to only "be" in widemode.
- After that it is necessary to use a "fixed" [EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUIUtility-labelWidth.html) namely reduced by the width the 3 `Vectror3` fields will take in widemode (Unity used 212)

Answer (score 1):

Unity3d has its [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference) available on GitHub, where you can see the [Transform](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/95eee03f136b8bf8a9afd5d43fef5b919ba90c55/Editor/Mono/Inspector/TransformInspector.cs) component implementation.

**TransformInspector.cs:**

```
/ Unity C# reference source
// Copyright (c) Unity Technologies. For terms of use, see
// https://unity3d.com/legal/licenses/Unity_Reference_Only_License

using UnityEngine;

namespace UnityEditor
{
    [CustomEditor(typeof(Transform))]
    [CanEditMultipleObjects]
    internal class TransformInspector : Editor
    {
        SerializedProperty m_Position;
        SerializedProperty m_Scale;
        TransformRotationGUI m_RotationGUI;

        class Contents
        {
            public GUIContent positionContent = EditorGUIUtility.TrTextContent("Position", "The local position of this GameObject relative to the parent.");
            public GUIContent scaleContent = EditorGUIUtility.TrTextContent("Scale", "The local scaling of this GameObject relative to the parent.");
            public string floatingPointWarning = LocalizationDatabase.GetLocalizedString("Due to floating-point precision limitations, it is recommended to bring the world coordinates of the GameObject within a smaller range.");
        }
        static Contents s_Contents;

        public void OnEnable()
        {
            m_Position = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocalPosition");
            m_Scale = serializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocalScale");

            if (m_RotationGUI == null)
                m_RotationGUI = new TransformRotationGUI();
            m_RotationGUI.OnEnable(serializedObject.FindProperty("m_LocalRotation"), EditorGUIUtility.TrTextContent("Rotation", "The local rotation of this GameObject relative to the parent."));
        }

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            if (s_Contents == null)
                s_Contents = new Contents();

            if (!EditorGUIUtility.wideMode)
            {
                EditorGUIUtility.wideMode = true;
                EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth = EditorGUIUtility.currentViewWidth - 212;
            }

            serializedObject.Update();

            Inspector3D();
            // Warning if global position is too large for floating point errors.
            // SanitizeBounds function doesn't even support values beyond 100000
            Transform t = target as Transform;
            Vector3 pos = t.position;
            if (Mathf.Abs(pos.x) > 100000 || Mathf.Abs(pos.y) > 100000 || Mathf.Abs(pos.z) > 100000)
                EditorGUILayout.HelpBox(s_Contents.floatingPointWarning, MessageType.Warning);

            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }

        private void Inspector3D()
        {
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(m_Position, s_Contents.positionContent);
            m_RotationGUI.RotationField();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(m_Scale, s_Contents.scaleContent);
        }
    }
}
```